# Using Ajax to update ViewBag data ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently have 2 class call City and District (1 to many relationship, respectively) .In my view I have 2 dropdown list, one for all the cities and the other for the districts (populated by using ViewBag). When a city is selected, I want the dropdown list for district to display only districts of that city without reloading the whole view. I had used Ajax before but only to re-populate data for model and not ViewBag. So how can I do it using Ajax and ViewBag ?

Comment: What u tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

you can't repopulate the ViewBag itself.

I don't know if this is the best way but I would have done it the following way:

HTML:

```
 <div>
   <select id="city">
     options
   </select>
 </div>
 <div id="district-select">
    <select>
    </select>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
$("#city").change(function() {
   var id = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url:"/CONTROLLER/GetDistrictsByCity",
     data: {cityId: id},
    success: function(data) {
       $("#district-select").html(data);
    }
   });
});
```

ACTION:

```
public ActionResult GetDistrictsByCity(Guid cityId){
   //GET Districts that is linked to the cityId

   return PartialView("_DistrictsByCity", model);

}
```

and then in the view "_DistrictsByCity" all you create is the dropdownlist. that html will then be taken and placed inside the div with the id "district-select"

Let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: Thats how I would do it, but i'm in no way an expert here. It would be awesome to hear from an expert about doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

it's bad idea to use ViewBag instead of StronglyTyped (Model)
so declare a ViewModel First and then pass your data to View via ViewModel